# Secure JMX and Prevent Remote client to register arbitary Mbeans JMX using javax.management.loading.MLet

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, java-security

Context: In our scenario we do not pass `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` hence we only run JMX for local monitoring. 
To monitor that prod host (call it  x) remotely from a client (call it y) a user can create ssh packet forwarding from the jmx service port on x (Assuming that user from y has access to public port serving JMX on x).

Correct me if I am wrong: Since user has access to JMX service port on X,  I assume this also gives user on y the power to use `javax.management.loading.MLet` to execute arbitrary code on prod host x.

From Orcales [Monitoring and Management](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) doc, is this safe to say that if we use Password authentication with configs

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
```

Does this make JMX access secure, that means is it safe to say users won't be able to use `javax.management.loading.MLet` to execute code on prod host x even though they have access to JMX serving port on it?

Any better suggestions on securing JMX?

Comment: if you don't specify `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` then is there a "jmx service port on x" at all?  Or are you saying you're thinking of adding one?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, but keep in mind that users will not be able to access JMX services at all unless they have the proper credentials. In other words, you are not just blocking MLet registrations, you are blocking everything. You should select your authentication method carefully as well. If you use property files, a user with SSH access to the file system may be able to acquire the credentials.

Comment: Thanks. Does this all work without enabling SSL too ? I mean just using Password authentication also prevents users to register arbitrary MBeans?

Comment: Yes it does. The SSL will ensure callers are not spoofed for credentials and in-flight data is encrypted.

Comment: what about the RMI registry port that opens up with JMX, that will still remain exposed right? Without SSL you can still exploit that port, although are you aware what data is exposed via that port?

Comment: The RMI port will provide the remote stub to connect to jmx, but credentials will still be required to issue JMX operations.

Comment: But can't this RMI port be used to get those credentials? This RMI port can be easily be figured out with ssh to host right ?

Comment: The rmi server doesn't know about the jmx credentials. It just serves an rmi remote stub that lets the jmx client locate the endpoint.